# Lucene Query API: multi filed fuzzy query

Tags: java, lucene, fuzzy-search

I am using Lucene 9.7.0 java library

I like the FuzzyQuery method for searching and my intention is to search phrases

Now my code is working fine but I think there should be more convenient way to do the same:

```java
new BooleanQuery.Builder()
    .add(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("title", analyzer.normalize(null, "foo")), 1), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
    .add(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("title", analyzer.normalize(null, "bar")), 1), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
.build()
```

Maybe something like that (I got it from Lucene's documentation):

```java
 String[] query = {"query1", "query2", "query3"};
 String[] fields = {"filename", "contents", "description"};
 BooleanClause.Occur[] flags = {BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD,
                BooleanClause.Occur.MUST,
                BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT};
 MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(query, fields, flags, analyzer);
```

I'd appreciate a hint